# Is there any way to configure ehcache to return an expired object if it is unable to obtain an updated version?

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache

Similar thread which talks about it - https://sourceforge.net/p/ehcache/discussion/322278/thread/cfe24a99/ This question was added in 2009 and I am clueless on how to integrate the solution with annotation based ehcache implementation.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do this by default in Ehcache, either 2.x or 3.x.

You will have to decorate the cache (Ehcache 2.x) or wrap your values (Ehcache 3.x) and devise exactly what you want on your own.